# Detect text between braces excluding strings. Partial code done

Tags: javascript, regex

I have almost zero experience with Regex. What I'm trying to do is to match text between braces, like this:

```
{([^}]*)}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tG7kC0/16

but do not match them when they are between quotes (single and double) and with escaping characters, like this:

```
(["'])(?:(?!\1)[^\\]|\\.)*\1?
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tG7kC0/15

I managed to create both regexes and I'm not sure if they are good or not. The thing is that I got them working separately. Now I want to unify them but I have no idea. How can I achieve this?

Comment: First, why ninja downvote? Second, @WiktorStribiżew, Thank you for your reply. Got it working. Going to learn about that and make it work in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript there's no real way to do that with the pattern only.

A simple workaround consists to join the two patterns in an alternation and to test the capture groups:

```
var re = /(["'])(?:(?!\1)[^\\]|\\[\s\S])*\1?|{([^}]*)}/g;
var str = 'asd + {ASD} + {A-._&SD} + "asd\\"{A-.\'_&SD}" + \'a\\\'s\\\\d\' + "" + \'\'';
var m;
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (!m[1])
      console.log(m[2]);
}
```

In a replacement context, use a function as replacement parameter to do the same test:

```
var result = str.replace(re, function (m, g1, g2) {
    if (g1) return m;
    // do what you want with g2
    return '#' + g2 + '#';
});
```

Comment: Still better than a direct programming approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
\{([^}\"']+)\}(?!['"])
```

https://regex101.com/r/tG7kC0/21

`(?!['"])` - lookahead negative assertion, matches words enclosed with curly braces if they are not between quotes

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, agreed, fixed

Comment: That's way better than what I was trying. I started with one small thing and ended with a big monster xD Going to analyze it.

You being both kind guys helping here, can you explain me why I'm getting downvotes? I know that this may be a newbie question, but I'm not a regex guy and cannot waste more time on this. Was asking here or making a programming solution instead of a regex one.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález, there's a lot of haters on SO, they like downvoting

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález: if I were you, I will write the patterns in the question itself.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, I can't say that I understood your comment completely. What concrete part of my regex is problematic? I'm trying to make it good as possible. You meant the first assertion `(?!["'])` should be a lookbehind?

Comment: this one: `(?!["']){`. remove the first lookahead, and you will obtain exactly the same result. A lookbehind will be Indeed more logical, but even if it was possible (javascript) I don't think it can handle all cases.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Oh, thank you. RomanPerekhrest, I have a problem with this pattern. This pattern do not match elements that have a quote right to them and also match elements between quotes, like this: https://regex101.com/r/tG7kC0/22

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález: add the example string too.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: unfortunately, I think that the only way is to check all the string from the beginning (or the previous match) to be sure that there isn't an opening quote before.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte With th string `asd + {ASD}" {ASD} "`, for example. The first ASD is not matched and the second one does.